# SVG & font metrics

Tags: fonts, svg, font-size

Is there any means to get font metrics in SVG?
I'd like to get: descent, ascent, max height, advance.

I need this for drawing text & graphics together like in flowcharts.

For example, I need to draw a box around text, and to draw a connector line from the middle of ex-size(size of letter 'x'), and not from the center of the box side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have DOM access then there are a number of [SVG DOM methods for text elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#InterfaceSVGTextContentElement). Then there's the [getBBox](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#InterfaceSVGLocatable) method which is available on most svg elements.

If you're dealing with SVGFonts, then the data is already available in xml format as normal attributes, e.g [ascent, descent](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/fonts.html#FontFaceElement) etc.

For your use-case I'd recommend `getBBox`, since it can deal with graphic elements too (in case you ever want to add more things than just text to the charts).

Comment: I would definitely _not_ recommend using `getBBox`, since it only respects the absolute bounds of the text. However, to place text correctly, once has to respect the ascent and descent. The `y` attribute of an SVGTextElement specifies the vertical position of the _baseline_. Therefore using only the `BBox` wouldn't help much. The problem is, the SVG DOM methods do not allow to query the ascent and descent information! I have no idea why this is lacking in the Spec.

Comment: To calculate descent, here's what I did.  Set "y" for the text element in SVG to zero.  Now your baseline is at zero.  Then get the "y2" property from getBBox and that will be the height of your "descent".